# Posting data to a specific path from multiple components

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, vue.js

Ok I'll try to explain this the best I can. I have a `ResourceInfo` component that posts data to the `/resources/` path and `/users/ + uid + /created-resources` path using `newPostKey`and update.

I also have a `QuizBuilder` component. I want to post data from this component to a `/resources/ + newPostKey + /quiz/` path. However, I don't know how to get the `newPostKey`or key from that particular path I created in `ResourceInfo` from the `QuizBuilder` component.

Here are the two components. First the user adds info using the `ResourceInfo` component. Once they hit submit they go to the `QuizBuilder` component where they create the quiz.

ResourceInfo.vue

```js
export default {
  name: 'resource-info',
  data () {
    return {
      header: 'Before you build your quiz we just need some quick info.',
      sharedState: store.state,
      resource: {
        type: '',
        title: '',
        url: '',
        desc: '',
        timesPassed: 0,
        authorId: store.state.userInfo.uid,
        authorName: store.state.userInfo.displayName,
        authorImage: store.state.userInfo.photoURL
      },
    }
  },
  methods: {
    saveToFirebase () {
      var newPostKey = firebase.database().ref().child('resources').push().key;
      var updates = {};
      updates['/resources/' + newPostKey] = this.resource;
      updates['/users/' + store.state.userInfo.uid + '/created-resources/' + newPostKey] = this.resource;

      // Clear inputs  

      this.resource.title = '',
      this.resource.type = '',
      this.resource.desc = '',
      this.resource.url = ''

      console.log("Saving resource data...")

      return firebase.database().ref().update(updates);

    }
  }
}
```

QuizBuilder.vue

```js
export default {
  name: "quiz-builder",
    data () {
    return {
      questions: [createNewQuestion()],
      showQuestions: false
    }
  },
  methods: {
    addQuestion () {
        this.questions.push(createNewQuestion())
    },
    addOption (question) {
        question.options.push(createNewOption())
    },
    saveToFirebase (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var questions = this.questions;
      this.firebaseRef = db.ref('a/path/here'); // /resources/ + that resources id + /quiz/
      this.firebaseRef.push({ // Should I use set or push here?  
      questions
    })

  console.log('Saving quiz data...')

    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer depends on how the transition between the components/pages are made.

- If you're building a single page app with vue-router or something, then the transition is replacing the former component with the latter, which all happens on the index.html, with no request sent(simplest situation). To still keep the generated key within our grasp after the first component is gone, you need to save it on a common parent of the two components. To be specific, add a `key` in the parent's data, and let the ResourceInfo emit a custom event with the generated key to notify the parent to set its key. See http://vuejs.org/guide/components.html#Using-v-on-with-Custom-Events .
- If you refreshes the page when jumping from ResourceInfo to to Quiz, with server-side rendering (which should be really rare, since it requires more effort compared to the single-page way, and has an inferior performance), then it's irrelavent to vue and rather simple: redirect the user to Quiz after ResourceInfo is saved, with the key as a url param.

Edit upon OP's using `store.js`:

Just store the `key` in `LocalStorage`(`store.js`) and retrive it from another component should work since LocalStorage is available globally and even across pages/sessions.

Some thought: `main.js just be the parent` is in some sense right. There's no real parent vue component here, but our main.js is evaled by the browser in the global scope, so it's true that main.js is the root entry of our app, aka parent.

Comment: Ok. It's the first option. But I store all my state in `store.js` and just set state in each component to `sharedState: store.state` I'm also using single file components and don't nest any components. Would `main.js` just be the parent then?

Comment: @staxwell not sure if you get notified on my edit. Let me know if it works.

Comment: Yeah. I ended up storing the key in the store.js file and grabbing it from there. Thanks for all your help! Helped me to the answer!